# Spring Data JPA NamedStoredProcedureQuery Multiple Out Parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple stored procedure I'm using to test out Spring Data JPA Stored Procedure feature.

```
create or replace procedure plus1inout (arg in int,res1 out int,res2 out int) is
BEGIN   
 res1 := arg + 1; 
 res2 := res1 + 1;
END;
```

My code is:

```
@Repository
public interface AdjudConverDateSPRepository extends JpaRepository<AdjudConverDateSP, Long> {
    @Procedure(name = "plus1")
    Object[] plus1(@Param("arg") Integer arg);
}

@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "plus1", procedureName = "ADJUD.PLUS1INOUT",
        parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "arg", type = Integer.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res1", type = Integer.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res2", type = Integer.class)
})
public class AdjudConverDateSP implements Serializable {
        //stub to satisfy hibernate identifier requirement
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

}
```

Everything works fine when I have a single OUT parameter. But once I add a second OUT parameter I get an exception saying it can't find the procedure in the entity.

```
Caused by:
  org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property plus1 found for type AdjudConverDateSP!  at
  org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) at 
  org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) at
  org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) at
  org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) at
  org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) at
  org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) at
  org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) at
  org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) at
  org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
```

Comment: Which Spring Data JPA version are you using?

Comment: Spring-Data JPA version 1.8.0

Comment: There's an issue in the git repo for this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/80 ... this would be the answer when they get to it.

Comment: Could you please try to replace `@Procedure(name = "plus1")` as `@Procedure("plus1inout")` or `@Procedure(procedureName="plus1inout") `

Comment: @HowardWang comment helped me for similar error. I was giving name under (name="proc"), but when I gave @Procedure("proc") it worked. Strange!

Answer (score 8):

It looks like `@Procedure` expects only one OUT parameter which is binded directly to the method return type...

To handle multiple OUT params you can use the JPA API directly:

```
StoredProcedureQuery proc = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("plus1");

proc.setParameter("arg", 1);
proc.execute();
Integer res1 = (Integer) proc.getOutputParameterValue("res1");
Integer res2 = (Integer) proc.getOutputParameterValue("res2");
...
```

Comment: Ultimately using JPA API is what I did. Where did you find that @Procedure expects only one OUT param?

Comment: The API excepts only one OUT param http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/Procedure.html

Comment: can you please provide complete example. i am new and not able to call Named Stored procedure through entity manager.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify to return one of the multiple out params with the `outputParameterName` param in the `@Procedure` annotation like this:

```
@Repository
public interface AdjudConverDateSPRepository extends JpaRepository<AdjudConverDateSP, Long> {
    @Procedure(name = "plus1", outputParameterName = "res2")
    Integer plus1(@Param("arg") Integer arg);
}
```

UPDATE 2019-06-24:

Multiple out parameters is now supported in Spring Data JPA 2.2-RC1
https://spring.io/blog/2019/06/17/spring-data-moore-rc1-and-lovelace-sr9-released

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-707

The interface method just needs to have a Map return type so each out param can be accessed by key name:

```
@Repository
public interface AdjudConverDateSPRepository extends JpaRepository<AdjudConverDateSP, Long> {
    @Procedure(name = "plus1")
    Map<String, Object> plus1(@Param("arg") Integer arg);
}
```

Comment: Jeff, I am trying to follow this link https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-707 but I am not able to get from which jar @Outparameters annotation is coming. I am using latest spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.5 release. can you please me out with info on jar needed? Thank you

Comment: @Khushi, i think that original description is a bit out of date. I believe you can specify using @ StoredProcedureParameter like this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/sample/User.java#L77

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I have posted a question regarding Stored proc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61454441/wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-while-calling-stored-proc .Can you please check and respond once.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data JPA support multiple output parameters. Return type of Method must be a Map. I spent a lot of time on this. Below link exactly gives example of that, Search for User.plus1IO2.

[User.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/sample/User.java#L77)

[UserRepository.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/e27933455efa6d1821dea23abd2bbe109b5d59a7/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L362)

Comment: what if you have 3 or more output parameters?

Comment: Yes, you can include all of them in the map. A map can hold as muliple key, values.

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys based on [Jeff Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469525/jeff-sheets) anwer got my problem solved so I'd like to also help a bit

here is my solution

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cardById`(IN id int, out cardNumber varchar(16), out personId bigint)
BEGIN
    SELECT card_number, person_id into cardNumber, personId 
    FROM cards 
    WHERE card_number = id
    LIMIT 1;
END
```

in entity class

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Card.cardById",
    procedureName = "cardById", parameters = {
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "id", type = String.class),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "cardNumber", type = String.class),
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "personId", type = Long.class)
```

In repository

```
@Procedure(name = "Card.cardById")
Map<String, Object> cardById(String id);
```

happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesn't support multiple out params just yet. There is a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-707) for this.

Comment: This should have been a comment as it does not fully answer OP's question