# CrudRepository - Stored Procedure call is not working because of type/number of argument issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have JPA entity as

[image]

And then Repository as

[image]

Now, when I run it then I get following exception:

[image]

And stored procedure is:

[image]

It is running against Oracle database. Can someone please help me understand even though I have correct parameter numbers and type, still why I am getting this exception.

**Please note:** I do not have local environment so I cannot put a sample code, and please do not worry about class/method name, I tried to camouflage them so they may be inconsistent.

There is one more question that suppose I have 2 OUT parameters then how you I create my entity class, with one output parameter I know I can return `String` (or appropriate return type) but in case of 2 OUT parameters I do no know how to do it? I have read [this](https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa) article but it is only with 1 OUT parameter, and I couldn't find any article or post which explains for 2 OUT parameter. If someone has a code with 2 OUT parameter then it would be helpful.

Comment: ..of course there should also be no confusion regarding `p_partition_creation` vs. `TEST_p_partition_creation`!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

- use the exact (db) names of procedure parameters:

  ```
  @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "tbl_name" ...
  @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "p_date" ...
  @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "p_message" ...
  ```
- or (alternatively) omit names completely (rely on position).

From  [StoredProcedureParameter javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureParameter.html#name--):

> The name of the parameter **as defined by the stored procedure in the database**. If a name is not specified, it is assumed that the stored procedure uses positional parameters.

---

Currently you [can't have multiple OUT-parameters using spring-data](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-707), but (should be) no problem with standard JPA:

```
StoredProcedureQuery spq = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("my_proc");
proc.setParameter("p_in", 1);
proc.execute();
Integer res1 = (Integer) proc.getOutputParameterValue("out1");
Integer res2 = (Integer) proc.getOutputParameterValue("out2");
```

see also: [Spring Data JPA NamedStoredProcedureQuery Multiple Out Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29899219/592355)

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. And how about handling 2 OUT parameters, can you please let me know your inputs for that as well? Once that is also done I can accept the answer.

Comment: you can't do it with spring(-data) yet (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-707), but it is possible via `EntityManager` : https://stackoverflow.com/q/29899219/592355