# wrong number or types of arguments while calling Stored Proc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I am calling Stored Proc from Spring Data JPA :

Procedure is:

```
create or replace procedure GET_LATEST_GC (arg1 IN VARCHAR2, res1 OUT VARCHAR2, res2 OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM GC_T WHERE id = arg1;

  COMMIT;

  BEGIN
    SELECT gc.NAME, s.SIP INTO res1, res2
    FROM GC_T gc, STAFF_T s WHERE s.id = gc.id 
    AND START_TIME = (SELECT MAX(START_TIME) FROM GC_T);

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN  
    res1 := '';    
  END;
END;
```

Spring Data JPA code

//Repository

```
 public interface ActiveDao extends JpaRepository<GcT,Integer>  {
        @Procedure(procedureName="GET_LATEST_GC")
        Object[] plus1(@Param("arg1") String arg1);
    }
```

//Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "GET_LATEST_GC",
        procedureName = "GET_LATEST_GC", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "arg1", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res1", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res2", type = String.class)})
@Table(schema = "abc", name = "GC_T")
public class GcT implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;


}
```

//Call

```
Object[] activeGCInfo =activeDao.plus1(arg);
```

Procedure is accepting one parameter and I am also passing 1 argument.Then also I am getting this error:

Hibernate: {call GET_LATEST_GC(?,?)}
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_LATEST_GC'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n

Please let me know where I am doing wrong. 
Thank you

**Update- Tried to add OUT params also as per suggestion**

```
//Repo
 public interface ActiveDao extends JpaRepository<GcT,Integer>  {
            @Procedure(procedureName="GET_LATEST_GC")
            Object[] plus1(@Param("arg1") String arg1,@Param("res1") String res1,@Param("res2") String res2);
        }

//Call
Object[] activeGCInfo =activeDao.plus1(arg,"","");
```

I am sending three args but it is showing me 4 args in error:

> Hibernate: {call GET_LATEST_GC(?,?,?,?)} SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'GET_LATEST_GC'\nORA-06550: line 1, column
>   7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n

Comment: try to set the same name for param (arg1 != arg)

Comment: sorry, it was typo.In code, it is same only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the result from Object[] to `Map<String, Object`, along with referencing the proc name with `name` instead of procedureName. Based on the error, I'm not sure that it will fix it. Spring Data JPA does expect a Map as the return value for multiple output params, so each output param can be found as the key in that Map. But I think the main error is that procedureName maps directly to the db, but `name=` will map to the correct Entity

```
//Repo
 public interface ActiveDao extends JpaRepository<GcT,Integer>  {
            @Procedure(name="GET_LATEST_GC")
            Map<String, Object> plus1(@Param("arg1") String arg1);
        }

//Call
Map<String, Object> activeGCInfo =activeDao.plus1(arg);
```

Comment: Hello Jeff,Big thank you. Now I am able to get 2 out params :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened:

- you declared a procedure with 3 parameters: 1 in and 2 out
- you said: "Procedure is accepting one parameter and I am also passing 1 argument"

  - that was the 1st procedure's parameter (`arg1 IN`)
  - it results in "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments"

Of course it does; you need to provide 2 more *arguments* (datatype should be able to accept `VARCHAR2` values returned by the procedure).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to add out params in repository method.Now error changed to 4 args while I need to send only 3 params.Is the syntax correct? I checked in Spring doc but they have given example with one argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know Spring; all I can do is to *point* you to what you did wrong as of Oracle side of the story.

Comment: np Littlefoot, anybody else who can point out to the issue.Thanks